# Missing stack exchange profiles on careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, jobs, stack-exchange

On [my careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/lhunath) it appears that I cannot add any of my stack exchange accounts, other than Super User, to my profile.  All my stack exchange accounts use the same OpenID (lhunath@lyndir.com - Google).  The Stack Exchange section does however enumerate my answers from Stack Overflow.  This looks buggy.

Comment: What exactly do you see when trying to add by clicking the "edit" link to the right of "Stack Exchange Accounts"? Can you post screenshot?

Comment: @lhunath Confirmed... We'll hook them up for you.

Comment: I'm having this problem also - when I say "edit", it says, "Please select the Stack Exchange network sites you'd like to display on your profile", then there's nothing, then there's an orange "Save" button.  Under "Add an Answer" it says "Sorry, you don't seem to have any answers on that site. " for StackOverflow.  I've tried linking everything on the same openID and all that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All your accounts have been linked to your careers profile.

Comment: How can I see my linked accounts on my career profile? Becoz when I try to edit it, it says, "Please select the Stack Exchange network sites you'd like to display on your profile", then there's nothing, then there's an orange "Save" button. I can't see any stack exchange sites.

Comment: @user370305 sometimes it takes a day or so for everything to sync up, but it looks like you're all set at the moment.