# can't access stack exchange sites via careers "top answers"

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs, stack-exchange

I tried tagging along with the same issue over on [Missing stack exchange profiles on careers profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124987/missing-stack-exchange-profiles-on-careers-profile) but haven't gotten a response.   Basically nothing shows up underneath "Stack Exchange - Top Answers" when I edit my "careers" profile, there's no listing of stack exchange sites to choose from - I'm user "zzzeek" on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/users/34549/zzzeek.   I tried changing my email address to be identical on careers vs. stackoverflow, tried setting up the same kind of openID access via google, no dice.

From other answers it seems like this is something that needs to be fixed on the SO end.

Comment: Looking into this... Stay tuned

Comment: I seem to be getting results now, "add an answer" now shows a bunch of stackoverflow answers I can choose from whereas before it wasn't doing that.

Comment: I can also add answers, but I don't see anything about sites. Hitting edit makes a box appear, but nothing in it can be  selected.